# Are all henselian fields algebraic over complete fields?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

#### Motivations and Terminology

The term "henselian field" is ambiguous. What I mean when I say that $K$ is a henselian field is that there exists a henselian DVR $R$, such that $K=Frac(R)$. What I mean when I say that $L$ is a complete field is that there exists a complete DVR $S$ such that $L=Frac(S)$.

Note that every complete field is henselian. Examples of complete fields are $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ (the field of formal Laurent series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$), $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (the $p$-adics), and so forth.

When I try to think of henselian fields that are not complete, the ones that immediately come to mind are algebraic over some complete field. For example $\mathbb{Q}((t))(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}_p^{un}$ (the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$), and so forth.

#### Question

Is it true that for every henselian field $K$ there exists a subfield $L\subset K$ such that $L$ is complete and such that $K/L$ is an algebraic extension?

EDIT: I've re-emphasized this in the comments, but I think it is important to put this in the body of the question: both the term "henselian field" and "complete field" are used in many different contexts to mean different things.

Note that under the definitions above $\mathbb{R}$ does not constitute as a complete field. (This is because $\mathbb{R}$ is not the fraction field of a complete DVR.)

Also note that I do not consider $\mathbb{Q}((t^{1/n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be a henselian field. (This is because my definition of a henselian field requires it to be the fraction field of a henselian DVR, not a general henselian ring.)

Comment: Do you consider $\mathbf R$ to be a complete field?

Comment: No. I defined "complete field" to mean the fraction field of a complete DVR.

Comment: Note also that it is not true that the fraction field of a general henselian ring is a "henselian field" under my definition. Only the fraction field of a henselian DVR is a "henselian field".

Comment: How about the henselization of $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$, where $p$ is a prime?

Comment: Angelo, if I recall correctly the henselization of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the ring of algebraic $p$-adics, which is not a DVR.

Comment: There is a definition of 'Henselian' that is a little more intrinsic, and you can find this, for example, in Neukirch's book on algebraic number theory: A valued field is Henselian if, for any finite extension, there is a unique extension of the valuation to that extension. Your definition of Henselian would be the case where the valuation is discrete. In any case, as Angelo's comment shows, there are many examples of non-complete Henselian rings. Take any non-complete DVR and look at its Henselization!

Comment: Makhalan--The Henselization of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ can be constructed as follows: Take the ring of integers in the maximal algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that's unramified at $p$ and localize it at any prime over $p$. One shows that this ring is Noetherian, and is therefore a DVR.

Comment: Keerthi, I am not looking for examples of non-complete Henselian rings. (Indeed, I gave examples in the body of the question!) I am looking for henselian fields (in the sense above) that are not algebraic over complete fields (in the sense above). Unrelatedly, you said "take any non-complete DVR and look at its henselization". As I mentioned, that is in general not DVR.

Comment: Sorry, I was describing the strict henselization there. Your description of the henselization is correct, I think. Why do you think it's not a DVR?

Comment: Keerthi, is that true that its Noetherian? I was almost sure it isn't.

Comment: I believe that the ring of algebraic $p$-adics is not noetherian, although I could be wrong.

Comment: The henselization of a Noetherian local ring is certainly Noetherian. This is a general fact: Any direct limit of local Noetherian rings (with local morphisms) is again Noetherian.

Comment: Oh, well that's good to know.

Comment: The original question still stands, though.

Comment: Actually, you would need the maps to be flat as well, for this to be true, but this is the case in the construction of the Henselization. This is all explained very well in Raynaud's beautiful book on Henselian rings.

Comment: Really? It seems to be that Angelo's comment gives an example that's not algebraic over a complete Henselian field.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right! I was being silly.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure -- is it obvious that the ring of algebraic $p$-adics has only one prime ideal?

Comment: Actually, now I'm not so sure that's the right definition of the henselization. You have to localize at a prime above $p$, and then you have a henselization.

Comment: So in short there is no conclusion to the question yet...

Comment: No, there is. The henselization of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a henselian DVR that is not algebraic over a complete DVR!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the right definition. It's easy to check that $p\mathbb{Z}_p\cap \mathbb{Z}_p^{alg} = p\mathbb{Z}_p^{alg}$, so $\mathbb{Z}_p^{alg}$ is a DVR, with $p$ generating the maximal ideal. An equivalent construction is to take a maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which some place above $p$ is totally split, and then localize at that place.

Comment: @Keerthi, I propose that you post that as the answer to this question.

Comment: The henselization of a DVR is always a DVR.

Comment: It has been pointed out to me that my statement about direct limits of Noetherian local rings being Noetherian again is very false. For the precise statement, please see 10.3.1.3 in EGA III, Vol. 1. Essentially, one requires the maximal ideals to to stabilize eventually.

Comment: I think you can just argue by cardinality: a complete field has to be uncountable, but there exist countable Henselian fields. There are explicit examples above, but also the theory of Henselian fields is axiomatisable in first order logic, so it follows from basic model theory that there are countable models (with value group $\mathbf{Z}$)